# Add new rows for days and countries when there is no information

Tags: r

I am trying to add new rows to dataset about COVID with the following variables: country, date and cases.
Some days that there is no information about the cases. I would like to add a new row for that day and that country with NA in the cases. How could I do that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you share a small snippet of your data?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: You can look into `?tidyr::complete`